# all traffic going to Virtual Hosting

Tags: proxy, virtualhost, apache2

I have an application running at http://localhost:6512 and a virtual host definition as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName ldpmarmotta.example.com
        ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)$ http://localhost:6512/marmotta/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

I am getting two problems with the above definition:

1. All traffic to this server including http://example.com is being
   directed to  http://localhost:6512
2. A request to ldpmarmotta.example.com is being directed to
   http://localhost:6512. I was not expecting the URL to change but the
   response to return on ldpmarmotta.example.com

Answer (score 0):

You say: "*I have an application running at http://localhost:6512*" but in the context of your question (and of this very answer), it would be better to say:

- I'm running an HTTP daemon listening on port 6512; let's call it **my_daemon**. Please note that it's **not** Apache; it's another application;

Also, you say: "*[...] a virtual host definition as follows...*", and again, it would be better to say:

- I'm also running Apache, configured to listen on port 80 (and obviously  **NOT** listening on port 6512) and with a single VirtualHost defined. Specifically, the VirtualHost defined below [....]

Having said the above (BTW: Am I right? If not, please add comments), you say to have two problems.

As for the first one:

> *All traffic to this server including http://example.com is being directed to http://localhost:6512*

I would say that **IF** the hostname `example.com` resolve to one of the IP addresses of the host running Apache, **THEN this is an expected behaviour** as:

- the HTTP request generated by launching "http://example.com" is received by Apache (as it's listening on port 80 of the related IP address);
- as there is **NOT** an explicitely defined VirtualHost with `ServerName example.com`....
- ...Apache will serve the request via the first VirtualHost defined. And...
- as the first virtual-host is "your" one, then the HTTP request is "proxyed" to my_daemon and...
- as such, my_daemon will receive the HTTP request.

So, again, I don't see the problem.

Again, if I'm wrong with some assumptions, please, let me know.

---

As for your second "problem", I see that it covers two distinct points. First one is:

> A request to ldpmarmotta.example.com is being directed to
>   http://localhost:6512

and, again, this look to me as an expected behaviour, as it's exactly what you configured in your virtual-host.

Second point is:

> I was not expecting the URL to change but the response to return on
>   ldpmarmotta.example.com

I'm not 100% sure of what exactly you're trying to describe but... if I take out my (dusty) crystal-ball, I bet you're facing problems with **ProxyPassing**: you have your own HTTP daemon running (**my_daemon**) but you don't want to expose it directly to the Internet. So you put a standard Apache in front of it and... kindly ask Apache to ProxyPass HTTP requests back-and-forth the Internet and your daemon.
In such a scenario.... you simply have to rely on `ProxyPass` ***AND*** **`ProxyPassReverse`**.

Something like:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:6512/marmotta/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:6512/marmotta/
```

*(BTW: you used `ProxyPassMatch` but as the REGEX you defined it's matching... everything, than it's acting exactly like a standard ProxyPass. Hence, I suggest to use the latter, as it's slightly more efficient and more readable).*

As for `ProxyPass`/`ProxyPassReverse` detailed usage.... the web it's literally **FULL** of detailed tutorial/articles so.... it will be easy, for you, to get deeper to details :-)

HTH.